# Reload the table view of a UITableController when a app's delegate property is changed

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my iPhone app, I'd like to reload a table view when the list of items used to populate it (this list is a NSMutableArray property of the app's delegate) is modified.
What is the best way to do it ?
At first I though of a NSTimer but I guess this is not a correct way to go...
May KVO pattern do the trick ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KVO is the way to go, but you have to make sure that you make changes to the array using the appropriate accessor(s) so that the KVC/KVO mechanism Just Works.

As a minimum, change the `NSMutableArray` property using the using the mutable proxy returned by `mutableArrayValueForKey:`. [Apple's documentation suggests that you go further](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-BAJEAIEE):

> You are strongly advised to implement these mutable accessors rather
>   than relying on an accessor that returns a mutable set directly. The
>   mutable accessors are much more efficient when making changes to the
>   data in the relationship.
>
> In order to be key-value coding compliant for a mutable ordered
>   to-many relationship you must implement the following methods:
>
> - `-insertObject:in<Key>AtIndex:` or `-insert<Key>:atIndexes:`. At least one of these methods must be implemented. These are analogous to the
>     NSMutableArray methods `insertObject:atIndex:` and
>     `insertObjects:atIndexes:`.
> - `-removeObjectFrom<Key>AtIndex:` or `-remove<Key>AtIndexes:`. At least one of these methods must be implemented. These methods correspond to the
>     NSMutableArray methods `removeObjectAtIndex:` and
>     `removeObjectsAtIndexes:` respectively.
> - `-replaceObjectIn<Key>AtIndex:withObject:` or `-replace<Key>AtIndexes:with<Key>:`. Optional. Implement if benchmarking indicates that performance is an issue.
>
> The `-insertObject:in<Key>AtIndex:` method is passed the object to
>   insert, and an `NSUInteger` that specifies the index where it should be
>   inserted. The `-insert<Key>:atIndexes:` method inserts an array of
>   objects into the collection at the indices specified by the passed
>   `NSIndexSet`. You are only required to implement one of these two
>   methods.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want to do ;) http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:

And this is my recommended and I am very sure the best way.